# ios asihttprequest post string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, string, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest, its working fine for posting dictionaries to the web service in the body

```
     ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
```

but how can i use the

> ASIFormDataRequest

to send a single string?

something like

```
   ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setPostValue:token];
```

no value and key,just a string in the body,

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send data via POST but prefer to create the POST body yourself, use `appendPostData:` or `appendPostDataFromFile:`. The code goes something like this -

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request appendPostData:[@"This is my data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
```